# Replace backslash in hash array

Tags: regex, perl

I have the next piece of code

```
sub raw_query {

    my ($self,%args) = @_;

    state $global_id = int(rand(10000));


    $args{'jsonrpc'} = '2.0';
    if ($self->cookie) { $args{'auth'} = $self->cookie; }
    $args{'id'} = $global_id++;


    if ($self->{verbosity} == 1) {
       print Dumper(\%args);
    }
    %args=quotemeta %args;
    for (my $i=0; $i< $self->{retries}; $i++){
      my $response = eval { $self->{ua}->post($self->{server},
                                              'Content-Type' => 'application/json-rpc',
                                              'Content' => JSON->new->escape_slash->utf8->encode(\%args)) };
```

it returns me back slashes for some values and thus JSON encoding fails:

```
 \{
                                              'main' => '1',
                                              'hostid' => '1',
                                              'useip' => '1',
                                              'type' => '2',
                                              'bulk' => '1',
                                              'interfaceid' => '1',
                                              'ip' => '1.2.8.4',
                                              'port' => '1',
                                              'dns' => 'test'
                                            }
```

Could you please help to replace this backslah: from \{ to { ?

Comment: `%args = quotemeta %args` is very wrong, and you would have seen the warning `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`. Please don't ignore warnings. It's not obvious what you intend, but since you can't modify hash keys directly I would guess that you probably want to escape non-word characters in the hash *values*. That would go like this `$_ = quotemeta for values %args`. But are you sure that you want escaped characters in the body of your HTTP message?

Comment: How have you generated that output? You should show the code that produced it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not with original source code, it was with source code of Perl module which was used in this code. Once I corrected it - everything worked out. Thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have passed your arguments to the method as a hash reference

```
$self->raw_query( { a => 'b', c => 'd' } );
```

or perhaps

```
my %args = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );

$self->raw_query( \%args );
```

This should be

```
$self->raw_query( a => 'b', c => 'd' );
```

or

```
$self->raw_query( %args );
```